# Query builder Call to a member function createQueryBuilder() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oop, symfony

I'm trying to use Query Builder in Symfony2.3 and I keep getting the error:
`FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function createQueryBuilder()
 on a non-object in...line 45`

which is the second part of my query,

```
$query = $tokenobject->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t.token','t.user', 't.expirationdate')
        ->where('t.user = :username','t.token = :token')
        ->setParameter('username', $Username)
        ->setParameter('token', $Token)
        ->orderBy('t.expirationdate', 'ASC')
        ->setMaxResults(1);
```

The entire code if it helps:

```
$confirmationrepository = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('TravelTravelBundle:Confirmation')
        ->findByuser($Username);

        $query = $confirmationrepository ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t.token','t.user', 't.expirationdate')
        ->where('t.user = :username','t.token = :token')
        ->setParameter('username', $Username)
        ->setParameter('token', $Token)
        ->orderBy('t.expirationdate', 'ASC')
        ->setMaxResults(1);
        $token = $query->getResult();
```

I know for a fact `$confirmationrepository` is finding table column`'user'` properly and that `$Username` and `$Token` (being routed into controller) are set and routing properly.

Is there something wrong with my syntax, or is there some other explanation for what is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$confirmationrepository = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('TravelTravelBundle:Confirmation')
        ->findByuser($Username);
```

should be

```
$confirmationrepository = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('TravelTravelBundle:Confirmation');
```

Comment: Now i'm getting `FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder::getResult() `....line 51,

Line fifty one is the 3rd part:`$token = $query->getResult();`

Comment: @DavidEugenePeterson You have to call `getQuery` first on the `QueryBuilder`, then call `getResult` on `Query`.

Comment: very good, I'm on a tight deadline on this project and I did indeed look over `getResult`. I removed `->findByuser($Username);` and changed `$token = $query->getResult();` to `$token = $query->getQuery()->getResult();` and the controller is now returning properly again.

Answer (score 0):

->findByuser($Username); fetches an array of entries. So $confirmationrepository is an array, and not the repository class you expected. Just omit the findByuser line.